# Ansible Jinja Templating

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I have a dictionary like this:

```
users:
  sammy:
    status: employed
  chris:
    status: unemployed
  dan:
    status: employed
```

I need to design a jinja template so that the output is like the following, showing only the employed users in alphabetical order:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/dan>
      Require group dan
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/sammy>
      Require group sammy
</Directory>
```

So far I have got this template but can't figure out how to select the **employed users only** and have them **alphabetically**.

```
{% for user in users %}
<Directory /var/www/html/{{ user }}>
  Require group {{ user }}
</Directory>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please check [built-in filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters), `selectattr` and `sort` in particular.

Comment: Thanks again for the help @KonstantinSuvorov . What tool(s) do you use to debug Jinja templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ ansible_managed | comment }}

{% for user in users|dictsort %}
    {% if user.1.status == 'employed' %}
        <Directory /var/www/html/files/{{ user.0 }}>
           Require group portal_{{ user.0 }}
        </Directory>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```